# Телеграмм бот не создает кнопки

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Всем привет!Недавно изучаю программирование и в попытках создать чат-бота столкнулся с проблемой, что он просто не распознает код для кнопок, хотя реагирует на команду старт. Вот часть кода:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")
bot.set_webhook()


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    first_name = (f'<b>Привет, {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}! \nВыберете интересующую '
                  f'тему!</b>')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, first_name, parse_mode="html")
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Публикация объявления', callback_data='publish_advertisement'))
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Написать админу', callback_data='write_to_admin'))
    btn3 = markup.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Реклама и сотрудничество', callback_data='advertising_and_partnership'))
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

не могу понять в чем ошибка. Обновлял библиотеку telebot, чистил кеш бота, но не помогает

Comment: Клавиатуру нужно цеплять к сообщению. А ты просто ее создал и все

Comment: понял, спасибо большое